# ng-clss Token '.' is unexpected, expecting [:]

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to use ng-class inside ng-repeat,

```html
<div data-ng-repeat='item in rows'>    
  <div class="repeat" data-ng-class="{ item.parent? 'parent': 'child'}">
  ...
  </div>
</div
```

But I have no clue why I get the following error:

> Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 7 of the expression [{ item.parent? 'parent': 'child'}]
>
> starting at [.parent? 'parent': 'child'}].

Comment: Try with two brackets like a `data-ng-class="{{item.parent? 'parent': 'child'}}"`

Comment: double bracket dont work for ngclass

Answer (score 2):

https://plnkr.co/edit/W8ptotfKDXUUFomvmsYH?p=preview

remove the { }

```
<div data-ng-repeat='item in rows'>    
  <div class="repeat" data-ng-class=" item.parent ? 'parent': 'child'">
    {{item.parent}}
  </div>
</div
```

or with bracket but no ternary

```
<div data-ng-repeat='item in rows'>    
  <div class="repeat" data-ng-class="{'parent':item.parent ,'child':!item.parent}">
    {{item.parent}}
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: In my case, item.parent is actually not a `boolean` value. Will it work?

Comment: what it is ? you can make it with `data-ng-class="( item.parent == 'test') ? 'parent': 'child'"`

Answer (score 1):

This is the way when you work with ng-class

```
<div class="repeat" ng-class="{
    'parent' : item.parent,
    'child' : !item.parent
}" </div>
```

Comment: In my case, item.parent is actually not a `boolean` value. Will it work?

Comment: Yes sure put a condition for `item.parent` as `item.parent === 'somevalue'` or `item.parent !== 'somevalue'`

Comment: Do you know you should accept best answer to make community effective, if somebody searching same problem they will see the best answer first. Please accept one of below answers –